# Parse server aws REST API error

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I created new parse server in amazon using bitnami image with parse dashboard, everything works fine but I am unable to connect parse REST api it throws error,

```
{"error":"unauthorized"}
```

I tried it with postman app

in my header

```
appId: ********************..
masterKey: *****************..
```

I send `GET` Request to this url

```
http://ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/parse/api/1/classes/_User
```

but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

two problems:

1. unless you have configured your parse server to include api/1 in the request uri, they don't belong there. The paths are a little different than parse.com.
2. you are using the wrong http headers.

Here's a curl that should work for you:

```
curl https://your.server:port/parse/classes/_User -H "x-parse-application-id: XXX" -H "x-parse-master-key: XXX"
```

Note that the path is: `parse/classes/_User`

And that the auth headers are: `x-parse-application-id` & `x-parse-master-key`

The good news is that the server response you are getting lets you know that parse-server is up and running and that's a big step ;)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
curl -X PUT \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"your_field":"your_data"}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes ##your url
```

Though New Parse Server do not require REST_API_KEY, using REST_API_KEY sometimes solve the problem. For Further reading please refer https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#objects-creating-objects

> I created new parse server in amazon using bitnami image with parse dashboard

I will suggest not to use bitnami image because when I was using this image a lot of features couldn't be used.